# ValidationException: the interface does not define a valid remote business interface; the method does not conform to RMI rules

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, rmi

I got the following exception on IBM WebSphere Application Server when starting my EJB application:

> com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: the interface
>   *YourInterface* does not define a valid remote
>   business interface; the method *yourMethod* does not conform to RMI rules

I checked [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbod.html) for the RMI confirmity rules, but that didn't help.
I also found a [problem ticket from IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM85177) describing exactly my problem, but giving an obscure solution by setting an undocumented JVM property - this didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that **one of my method's parameters didn't implement `java.io.Serializable`.**

So to tackle this rather generic error, you should check all your parameters that they implement this interface.

Comment: Or else are exported remote objects or their stubs. You need to check that the *actual values* implement Serializabable, not necessarily the formal parameters.